# C# Assigning values from List<string> to a string variable

Tags: c#

In Java, I can assign a value from Vector to a String variable.

```
String str = vector1.elementAt(0).toString();
```

How can I do the same thing in C# with List?

Thanks.

Comment: `string s = myList[0].ToString()` if it isn't a string, `string s = myList[0]` if `myList = new List<string>();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

Assuming

```
List<string> yourList;
```

Then all of the following would put the element in position `index` inside a string variable:

1. `string s = yourList[index];`
2. `string s = yourList.ToArray()[index];`
3. `string s = yourList.ElementAt(index);`

In all of the above, `index` must fall within the range `0 - (yourList.Length-1)` since array indexing in C# is zero-based.

This, on the other hand, while it would seem the same, won't even compile:

4. `string s = youList.Skip(index).Take(1);`

`.Take()` in this case doesn't return a `string` but a `IEnumerable<string>` which is still a collection.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> list = ...
...
string str = list[0];
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use index with the list.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string str = list[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`String str = vector1[0].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Creating a list of strings
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
...
//The string is filled with values, i is an int
string ithValue = lst[i];
```